# Min and max of a column duplicated across all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, max, normalization, min

I have an `orders` table with columns `supplier_id` and `revenue`:

[image]

A table of total revenue per supplier would be as follows:

```
SELECT
  supplier_id,
  SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
FROM
  orders
GROUP BY
  supplier_id
```

I would like to normalize the revenues from 0 to 1:

[image]

Thus, I will need the `min` and `max` of all the total revenues of all suppliers.

If possible, have these values as additional columns that are repeated per row:

[image]

How can I do this in MySQL?

Note that I would like the **`min` and `max` of the total revenues of all suppliers**, not the min and max revenue among orders per supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    t1.supplier_id,
    t1.total_revenue,
    t2.max_total_revenue,
    t2.min_total_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT 
        supplier_id,
        SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY supplier_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(total_revenue) max_total_revenue,
        MIN(total_revenue) min_total_revenue
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            supplier_id, 
            SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY supplier_id
    )
) t2 ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: **@Down_Voters** , Please give me the explanation. I think my answer produce correct output.

Comment: @FuzzyTree, thanks for the reminder of aliases. I've updated query with table aliases.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I tried it out among all the answers, and the results this query gives are as expected. @mmuzahid any chance we can improve performance?

Comment: @AdlerSantos , May be there is a better solution but at this moment I've no idea about that.

Comment: @AdlerSantos you could use `cross join` (and remove `on 1 = 1`) instead of `left join` but performance will probably be the same. a composite index on `(supplier_id,revenue)` might help

Comment: Totally agree, so I deleted my post in order to have only right solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using variables to determine the min and max

```
SELECT supplier_id,
    total_revenue,
    @min,
    @max
FROM (
    SELECT supplier_id,
        total_revenue,
        @min := coalesce(@min,total_revenue),
        @max := total_revenue
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            supplier_id,
            SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY supplier_id
        ORDER BY total_revenue
    ) t
) t
```